# How to import three.js GLTFExporter in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I'm trying to use `GLTFExporter` in a three.js typescript project.
I'm using the sample starter at https://github.com/pinqy520/three-typescript-starter and only adding these lines to the `render` function:

```
console.log(`type of exporter = ${typeof(THREE.GLTFExporter)}`)
let exporter = new THREE.GLTFExporter()
exporter.parse(scene, (gltf) => {console.log("Parsed scene!"); }, {});
```

But when I do `npm start` to run it in the browser, `THREE.GLTFExporter` is undefined so it's "not a constructor" (of course).
I suspect this is because the typescript type `GLTFExporter` is exported in the `three-gltfexporter.d.ts` but the actual class is not actually exported from its source in `node_modules/three/examples/js/exports/GLTFExporter.js` (there's no `export` keyword there). But I'm still very new at typescript so it could be me not understanding something. But all the "usual" parts of three.js get imported just fine, so I suspect something about the fact that `GLTFExporter` is only defined in `examples/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to put `THREE` in the global scope and then import the GLTFExporter, because the GLTFExporter file expects to find `THREE` in the global scope in order to add to it:

```
(<any>window).THREE = THREE;
import "three/examples/js/exporters/GLTFExporter";
```

It would be better if `@types/three` had an individual declaration file with a module augmentation of `three` for each optional extension such as `GLTFExporter` instead of declaring all the optional extensions unconditionally, so that TypeScript would be able to warn you about the problem at compile time.  Consider filing a bug on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/).

Comment: I'll file the bug, thanks.
When I try the import as you suggest, I get "THREE is not defined" when loading GLTFExporter.js at runtime. This is even though before that line I have `import * as THREE from 'three';` in my index.ts. I'd also expect there to be an `export` declaration somewhere in GLTFExporter.js, right?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a step; I updated the answer.  The import is only importing `THREE` into the scope of `index.ts` and does not make it visible to `GLTFExporter.js`.  The easiest way to make it visible there is to make it global.  `GLTFExporter.js` does not need an `export` because it is only adding to the existing `THREE` object.

Comment: Thanks, that works! (Still doesn't work in the larger project I'm working on but it answers this question anyway.)